# How to use categories c#?

Tags: c#

I need to solve the following task:

Create a class, `YahtzeeScorer`, with a method `int Score(string roll, Category category)` which can score the category Ones. Given the roll “1,2,3,4,5” and the category ones, the method should return 1.

I have implemented methods to score the different categories in Yahtzee, but can't figure out how to use categories to decide which test/method to run.

I have implemented:

```
public int scoreOnes(String roll)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (char c in roll) 
    {
        if (c == '1')
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Comment: switch (category) { case Categories.Ones: return countNumberOf(roll, 1); ...}